# Is it better to instantiate an InputReader for each method or to add it as a class attribute?

Tags: java, input, inputstream, bufferedreader, java-io

I have a java class that functions as a text-based UI for my project. To help me separate the sections of the UI, I have created a different method for each section (e.g.: mainUI, loginUI, searchUI...). The main first calls loginUI, then calls mainUI, and inside mainUI there are the calls to the other UIs.

Each section must read from user input to do various things, and I achieved that by using a BufferedReader like this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
br.readline();
```

Instead of creating a new BufferedReader for each method, or passing the first one I initialize to subsequent methods called, would it be okay to add it as a class variable?

Comment: You have to use a single `BufferedReader` for the life of the connection, and probably a single `InputStreamReader` too. Otherwise you will loae buffered data.

Comment: @user207421 so if I add br as a class variable and then initialize it when the software starts up, that would be right?

Comment: Sure, or pass it around as a parameter.